# How to set JAVA_HOME and NUTCH_JAVA_HOME in ubuntu., I tried but while compile nutch with ANT but getting this error

Tags: software-installation, java, environment-variables, jdk, solr

I'm very new to ubuntu, I have installed java and while compiling nutch am getting this error.

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/surukam/Desktop/Nutch/nutch/build.xml:101: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
```

Perhaps `JAVA_HOME` does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre`
I tried to check java location with `which java` It shows /usr/bin/java. I tried to set java with `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java` and tried to compile it shows `JAVA_HOME` not set in this path, It accepts when i gave this `export JAVA_HOME=/usr`. Now my question is I need to set my `JAVA_HOME` in this path `JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"` and 
 `NUTCH_JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"`. can anyone help me with this ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Unable to find a javac compiler;` suggesting that it is unable to find javac compiler, which is the `javac` binary. Try searching for javac on your system running `javac -version` and you can be sure if javac compiler is installed or not.

The package that provides `java` is `openjdk-8-jre`, by default it doesn't come with the javac compiler, only Java runtime environment. To install `javac`, run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` which will install `javac`, you can be sure if it is installed running `which javac` or `javac -version` after installation is done.